# Wordpress, changes to local copy changes live site

Tags: wordpress, local, live

I've been tasked with creating new content for at Wordpress site. To do this i've created a local copy og the site and database so i don't accidentally crash the live site. Then i created a few pages, did some css stuff, but then i got contacted by the site admin, who asked if i had changed anything or they had been hacked. I went to the live site and saw all the pages and css I had made was there.
Can anyone tell me why this is and how to change it? 
Thank you.

Comment: Your wp-config.php file in the copied site is using the same database. You should restore the original from the backup you made and change the values in the config file to the users and database.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it. I had changed some of the values but not DB-host, but it's working now so thanks